# Filter out groups that do not have a sufficient number of rows meeting a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

# Initialize dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['bar', 'foo'])
df1['bar'] = ['001', '001', '001', '001', '002', '002', '003', '003', '003']
df1['foo'] = [-4, -3, 2, 3, -3, -2, 0, 1, 2]
>>> print df1
   bar  foo
0  001   -4
1  001   -3
2  001    2
3  001    3
4  002   -3
5  002   -2
6  003    0
7  003    1
8  003    2
```

Consider the following threshold and parameters.

```
# Provide threshold and number of entries above and below threshold
threshold = 0
n_below = 2
n_above = 2
```

I would like to create a dataframe that filters out certain values of `bar`. The `bar`'s I want to filter out are the following: if it does not have at least `n_below` values of `foo` less than `threshold` and `n_above` values of `foo` greater than `threshold`.

For the above example:

- The group `bar = 001` would not be filtered out, since for `bar = 001` there are at least `n_below = 2` entries of `foo` less than `threshold = 0` and at least `n_above = 2` entries of `foo` greater than `threshold = 0`.
- The group `bar = 002` would be filtered out, since for `bar = 002` there are not at least `n_above = 2` entries of `foo` greater than `threshold = 0`.
- The group `bar = 003` would be filtered out, since for `bar = 003` there are not at least `n_below = 2` entries of `foo` less than `threshold = 0`.

The desired output would be the following:

```
# Desired output
   bar  foo
0  001   -4
1  001   -3
2  001    2
3  001    3
```

I believe this can be accomplished with GroupBy and `.count()`, however I have been unable to get a solution that works. I recognize that it may be cleaner to write a solution that does this in two steps: 1) first filters to meet the `n_below` condition; 2) then filters to meet the `n_above` condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `groupby` and `filter` methods.

```
threshold = 0
n_below = 2
n_above = 2
def filter_function(g):
    '''Called by filter, g is the grouped dataframe'''
    l = g['foo']
    return  (sum([x < threshold for x in l]) >= n_below 
            and sum([x > threshold for x in l]) >= n_above)

df.groupby('bar').filter(filter_function)

# gives
    bar foo
0   1   -4
1   1   -3
2   1   2
3   1   3
```

See [Pandas: Filtration](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration)

Answer (score 2):

I think there one of solution:

```
threshold = 1
n_below = 2
n_above = 2

df1.set_index('bar').loc[ \
    df1.groupby('bar')\
       .apply(lambda df_sub: \
                    (df_sub['foo']<threshold).sum()>=n_below \
                and (df_sub['foo']>threshold).sum()>=n_above)] \
.reset_index('bar')
```

and it returns

```
    bar foo
0   001 -4
1   001 -3
2   001 2
3   001 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
idx = df1.groupby('bar').apply(lambda x: (sum(x['foo'] < threshold) >= n_below) & (sum(x['foo'] > threshold) >= n_above))

print df1.set_index('bar')[idx].reset_index()

   bar  foo
0  001   -4
1  001   -3
2  001    2
3  001    3
```